# Defining directory and subdirectory in the subshell, simplification

Tags: bash, unix

Made the following script to run the app

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY=$(dirname $0)
LAST_VERSION=$(ls -t "$DIRECTORY"/new_version/ | head -1)

java -jar "$DIRECTORY/new_version/$LAST_VERSION"
```

I define the directory in which this script is located, then identify the latest version of the application in the subdirectory and run it.

I think it looks pretty cumbersome. It is annoying to reuse `DIRECTORY` variable, and repeating `new_version`. Just seems so "hard" for such a small script, or am I wrong? Maybe there's some way or tricks to make it easier? Thx.

Comment: What is `0_archive`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk fixed, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parameter expansion to remove the name of the script from `$0` and use a glob pattern to detect the jar file in the `new_version` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar "${0%/*}/new_version/"*.jar
```